# Check if element exists - Jasmine & Angular

Tags: angular, jasmine

I want to write a test to check if an element exists on the page after I click on it. So when I click on the element with the class "addItem", this element is hidden using an `*ngIf`. I tried it like this:

```js
it('Should handle click on .addItem button', () => {
    spyOn(component, 'addItem');
    addItemDebugElement = componentFixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.addItem'));
    addItemDebugElement.nativeElement.click();  //  click on the button
    expect(addItemDebugElement).toExist();
});
```

but it says: `Property 'toExist' does not exist on type 'Matchers<DebugElement>'.`
Can you please advise how to do this? Many thanks!

Answer (score 30):

I'd recommend you use

```js
//    Add Item Debug Ele comes out as null.
addItemDebugElement = componentFixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.addItem'));
expect(addItemDebugElement).toBeFalsy();
```

and...

```js
//    Add Item Debug Ele comes out as not null.
addItemDebugElement = componentFixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.addItem'));
expect(addItemDebugElement).toBeTruthy();
```

Comment: Yes. We can also use toBeNull() in null scenario.